# Remove the "blockiness" in Progress Bar in WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I want to remove the spaces between the blocks showing the progress. 
I need it to be solid.

Code:

```
<ProgressBar Name="probar"  Minimum="0" Height="40"  BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Geetha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the template of the `ProgressBar`. Fortunately, it's not very complex... The simplest way is to extract the template with a tool like [Style Snooper](http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/05/Revamped-Style-Snooper.aspx), the [BAML Viewer](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer) Reflector Add-in, or [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091), and change the part that defines the background.